# No route for new registration action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my registration controller I have the following code:

```
    def payment
    end
   protected
   def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    '/users/sign_up2'
   end
```

in my routes.rb:

```
 devise_for :users, controllers: { :registrations =>   "users/registrations"}
 devise_scope :user do
   get 'registration/sign_up2', to: 'registrations#payment'
 end
```

I get the following error:

No route matches [GET] "/users/sign_up2"

What im I doing wrong?

Comment: Not drinking enough coffee.

Answer (score 0):

Your route should be:

`get 'users/sign_up2', to: 'registrations#payment'`

where the left string is the URI and the right is the controller#method.

Alternatively you can modify after_sign_up_path_for to match the URI in the route.

Comment: I tried that route and the new error is: uninitialized constant RegistrationsController

Comment: this did it: get 'users/sign_up2', to: 'users/registrations#payment'